# How do I prevent the Order_ID's from repeating?

Tags: sql-server-2008

When I run this query, I get duplicate lines. Specifically, the order_ID is repeated for every possible ship_state related to that Customer_ID. If I remove the cust_address table from the query, I get the correct number of lines. How can I get just the Ship_states related to that particular order. Thanks.

```
SELECT     
    co.ID AS order_ID, 
    col.PART_ID, 
    col.ORDER_QTY, 
    co.STATUS, 
    co.SHIPTO_ID, 
    co.CUSTOMER_PO_REF, 
    co.CUSTOMER_ID, 
    c.STATE AS Bill_State, 
    ca.STATE AS Ship_State
FROM         
    dbo.CUSTOMER_ORDER AS co 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.CUST_ORDER_LINE AS col ON co.ID = col.CUST_ORDER_ID 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.CUSTOMER AS c ON co.CUSTOMER_ID = c.ID 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.CUST_ADDRESS AS ca ON c.ID = ca.CUSTOMER_ID
WHERE     
    (co.ORDER_DATE > '2014-01-01') AND (co.ID NOT LIKE 'rma%')
ORDER BY order_ID
```

Comment: you are clearly missing a column on the join condition with `CUST_ADDRESS` then, we can't help you more than that without knowing what's the structure and data of that table

Comment: When you say I'm missing a column on the join condition, do you mean I need to add another join condition or modify the current one? Thanks.

Comment: You probably need another join condition there. You have more than one address per customer in that table, that's why you get duplicate results

Comment: The shipto_id in the customer_order table and the shipto_id in the cust_address table contain the same information, but they are not PK's or FK's. I joined on them to try and link the co table to the ca table, but I still get repeated lines. What should I be looking for to tie everything together?

Comment: Well, if you know the right column then why are you using another column in the join condition?

Comment: The join condition I used originally was a join between the PK's. when I join cust_address on customer_order using shipto_id, I get 3 duplicate orders. far less than before, but still not there yet.

Comment: If it is the primary key then I don't see how you could get duplicates, unless there's another problem

Comment: The customer table has customer_ID as PK and so does the cust_address table. The customer_order table has the customer_ID column, but the PK is order_ID in both customer_order and cust_order_line. Getting all this information into unique lines has been the challenge.

Answer (score 0):

This gave me unique order lines and order numbers for each shipping address. The next challenge is to figure out a way to populate the rows that have the same shipping and billing address. For these orders the shipping fields are null and information from the customer table is used instead.

```
SELECT    ca.STATE AS ship_state, 
          co.ID, 
          co.CUSTOMER_ID, 
          ca.ADDR_NO, 
          co.SHIP_TO_ADDR_NO, 
          c.STATE AS Bill_state, 
          c.NAME AS Bill_name, 
          ca.NAME AS Ship_name
FROM    
        dbo.CUST_ORDER_LINE AS col 
FULL OUTER JOIN
        dbo.CUSTOMER_ORDER AS co ON col.CUST_ORDER_ID = co.ID 
FULL OUTER JOIN
        dbo.CUST_ADDRESS AS ca 
FULL OUTER JOIN
        dbo.CUSTOMER AS c ON ca.CUSTOMER_ID = c.ID 
ON      
        co.CUSTOMER_ID = c.ID 
AND     
        co.CUSTOMER_ID = ca.CUSTOMER_ID 
AND     
        co.SHIP_TO_ADDR_NO = ca.ADDR_NO
WHERE     
       (co.ORDER_DATE > '2014-1-1') AND (co.ID NOT LIKE 'rma%')
ORDER BY co.ID
```